# jQuery select rows without a td with a defined class

Tags: jquery

I am writing some jquery that turn the rows of a datatable http://www.datatables.net/ 
into clickable links. On click, the jquery takes the value from the hidden first column and appends this to a link.

I have this working, However, when there are no records returned. It still generates a row, which is clickable, but has it has no value, creates a dead link.

So i want to make all the rows clickable except the one created when there is no records returned.

When there are no records returned the row contains a cell with a class='dataTables_empty'. So i want to exclude this row.

So i need to specify a selector that will allow me to select all rows in the table except the row with a td with a class of dataTables_empty.
Here is my attempt if someone could help me out that would be appreciated.

```
$("#table_list").on("click", "tbody tr:not('td .dataTables_empty')", function (e) {
        var id = table.fnGetData(this, 0);
        document.location.href = "test.cshtml?ID=" + id;           
});
```

Comment: `"tbody tr:not('td .dataTables_empty')"` => `"tbody tr:not('td.dataTables_empty')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) combined with your `:not`:

```
$("#table_list").on("click", "tbody tr:not(:has(.dataTables_empty))", function (e) {
        var id = table.fnGetData(this, 0);
        document.location.href = "test.cshtml?ID=" + id;           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
$("#table_list").on("click", "tbody tr:not('> td.dataTables_empty')", function (e) {
        var id = table.fnGetData(this, 0);
        document.location.href = "test.cshtml?ID=" + id;           
});
```

You could also use the render method provided by datatables to render each column as an actual link, and you would have no need to bind jquery to any cells generated by datatables.
http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 0,
    "data": "download_link",
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
         var id =full[0];
      return "<a href='test.cshtml?ID="+ id +"'>"+data+"</a>";
    }
  } ]
} );
```